# How can I write duplicate files that are equal to or greater than 1GB to a excel file in Matlab?

Tags: performance, matlab, duplicates, byte, export-to-excel

The script below detects all duplicates from a given directory.
I'd like to edit this script so that only duplicates equal to or greater than 1GB are printed to an excel file.

```
root = 'C:\Users\19108\Documents';
dirlist = dir(fullfile(root, '**\*.*'));
filelist = dirlist(~[dirlist.isdir]);`
isunique = cell(size(filelist));

names = {filelist.name};

for i = 1:length(filelist)
    temp = [];
    for j = 1:length(filelist)
        if (i~=j)
            if isequal(name(i),name(j))
                if isempty(temp)
                    temp = j;
                else
                    temp = [temp,j];
                end
                isunique{i} = temp;
            end
        end
    end
end


fl_T = struct2table(filelist);
merge_T = [isunique, fl_T];
merge_T.Properties.VariableNames("name") = "Dup_Row";

%writetable(merge_T,filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

I reworked a bit your code while i was at it. Now it has one less loop and concatenates in a less verbose way.

```
root = 'C:\Users\19108\Documents';
dirlist = dir(fullfile(root, '**\*.*'));
filelist = dirlist(~[dirlist.isdir]);

names = {filelist.name};
uniqueFiles={};
for nn = 1:size(filelist,1)
    currFile=names{nn};
    currFileProperties=dir(currFile);
    if ~isempty(currFileProperties) %can happen that dir returns empty structs
    if and(sum(strcmp(currFile,names))>1, currFileProperties.bytes > 1e9)
        uniqueFiles={uniqueFiles{:},names{nn}};
    end
    end       
end
bigDupTab=cell2table(uniqueFiles',"VariableNames","BigDuplicates");
writetable(bigDupTab,filename);
```

The main points are:

- size() is more reliable and faster than length since length under the rug is nothing more than max(size(..))
- it is good practice not to loop using i as an index. Too similar to 1
- the dir() command returns a struct in which there is as a property the size of the file (in bytes). We can use this information to check the 1GB threshold.
- if you can use logical comparison it's better than looping. That's how i check for suplicates. The strcmp() checks for occurrencies returing a logical array, the sum counts the occurrencies.
- with a logical AND (&&) you can inline multiple if statements to use less lines and a clearer condition. The main if has the check of uniqueness and the check of size all together.
- concatenation doesn't really need to have a check for the first member, it it is empty it will manage it on its own

Probably there is some other ways to improve the code by preallocating but like this is think is good enough.